# Expansion of Cyclotomic polynomial on input $x+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I've been wondering why $$x^{p-1}+x^{p-2} + \dots + x + 1$$ expands to $$x^{p-1} + \binom p 1x^{p-2} + \binom p 2x^{p-3} + \dots + \binom p 1$$ when substituting $x$ for $x+1$ ?

Can someone clarify this ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are applying the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) to get that expansion.  In particular:

$$(x+1)^p = x^p + \binom{p}{1}x^{p-1} + \binom{p}{2}x^{p-2} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \binom{p}{p-1}x + 1$$

Crunching out the algebra (subtract $1$, divide by $x$), you should find that your result matches theirs.  Note that $\binom{p}{p-1} = \binom{p}{1}$ due to Proposition $4.1.1$ [here](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4205/files/CM4.pdf).

From there, you can simply apply Eisenstein's criterion to show irreducibility since $p|\binom{p}{k}$ for all $0 < k \leq p-1$.  At that point, you've shown that the original polynomial is irreducible since $f(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible $\iff f(x+c)$ is irreducible for any $c \in F$.

Comment: OP didn't ask for irreducibility, and just the "equation" only....

Comment: @8pir, I addressed the OP's question and added a bit more so that we could engage in some further Q&A if he wished.  That is, if later parts of the proof were fuzzy.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer Kaj. This clears things out.

Comment: @user111854, Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Observe that: $(x+1)^p - 1 = x^p + \binom{p}{1}x^{p-1} + \binom{p}{2}x^{p-2} + ...+ \binom{p}{1}x$. Thus divide both sides by $x$ to get the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it.